# How to append rows to a table using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

using jquery, I'm trying to add to a new row in a html table whatever the user input to the form . the form also have validation using php. validation works but displaying the inputs in the table don't. the new row of data will show only for a split seconds. i dont know what's the error cause Im new to jquery and php...

```
<?php 

    //declaring variables to null
    $f_name = $l_name = $email = '';
    $f_nameERR = $l_nameERR = $emailERR ='';


// On submitting form below function will execute.

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

if (empty($_POST["fname"])) {
$f_nameERR = "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible' role='alert'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>First name is required </div>";
} else {
$f_name = $_POST["fname"];
}


if (empty($_POST["lname"])) {
$l_nameERR = "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible' role='alert'> <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>Last Name is required </div>";
} else {
$l_name = $_POST["lname"];
}

if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
$emailERR = "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible' role='alert'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>Email Address is required </div>";
} else {
$email = $_POST["email"];
}


}
     ?>
```

I used Bootsrap in creating the form and table

```
<div class="container">
<div class="jumbotron">
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
<p>...</p>
<p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<ol class="breadcrumb">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
```

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="padding:25px 25px 25px;">
        <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert"> <p>Fill out the form below and click the 'Add' button</p></div>
        <form method="post" id="post_data">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="first_name">First </label>
                <input type="text" id="fname" class="form-control" name="fname"  placeholder="Enter First Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="first_name">Last </label>
                <input type="text" id="lname" class="form-control" name="lname"  placeholder="Enter Last Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email_add">E-mail Address</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" name="email"  placeholder="Enter Email">
                <p> We'll never share your email with anyone else.</p>
            </div>
            <button class="btn-primary" type="submit" id="mySubmit" value="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

```
    <div class="col-sm-9" style="padding:25px 25px 25px;">
    <?php echo $f_nameERR; ?>
    <?php echo $l_nameERR; ?>
    <?php echo $emailERR; ?>

<hr>
        <table class="table" id="table">
<thead>
        <tr style="background-color: #696969; color:white">
          <th > # </th>
          <th> First</th>
          <th> Last </th>
          <th> E-mail </th>
        </tr>  
</thead>              


<tfoot>


</tfoot>


    </table>

    </div>

</div>
```

and my Jquery

```
<script src="vendors/jquery-3.3.1.js">  </script> 
<script src="vendors/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
  var counter =1;
$("#addrow").on("click", function () {


    var _fname = $("#f_name").val();
    var _lname = $("#l_name").val();
    var _email = $("#e_mail").val();



    $("#table > tbody:last").after('<tr><td>' +counter+ '</td><td>'+ _fname +'</td><td>' +_lname+ '</td><td>' +_email+ '</td></tr>');
      counter++;
});

});


$('#myAlert').on('closed.bs.alert', function () {


});






</script>
```

Comment: Where are you doing the POST?

Comment: Do you want to add a row to the table which id="table"?
If so, do you want to add a row between thead and tfoot? Or elsewhere?

Comment: You need to append the row inside the TR. Adding a div inside tables will not render your HTML. Try adding an ID on the container you want to append and try something

$('#table tr:first-child').append('#theidofthecontainerrowyouwanttoappend');

Comment: the new row will display but it will disappear

Comment: If you're not submitting the form using AJAX, you'll lose any changes to the page on submit.

Comment: how can i convert the values into text?

Answer (score 0):

You should have the tbody first then append the rows there, you can loop the result and append it to the table tbody

this causing the problem, wrong id was used in jquery

```
  var _fname = $("#f_name").val();  should be $("#fname").val(); 
  var _lname = $("#l_name").val();  should be $("#lname").val(); 
  var _email = $("#e_mail").val();  should be $("#email").val();
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){


$("#table > thead").after('<tbody></tbody>'); 

for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
{

$("#table tbody").append('<tr><td>'+i+'</td><td>Juan_'+i+'</td><td>Delacruz</td><td>juandelacruz_'+i+'@gmail.com</td></tr>');

}

});
```

```css
table{width:100%; border-collapse: collapse;}
thead{background-color:#eee;}
th, td{padding:5px; text-align:left; border:solid 1px #f1f1f1;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- You should have the tbody first then append the rows there -->

<table id="table">
  <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th><th>First name</th><th>Last name</th><th>Email</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: this will work on displaying the infos on the table but the validation won't,. the user must fill all the inputs before it will display on the table.. i cant do this right

Comment: Execute only the line above after you validate the user input. the validation must be done in back-end php, then send a response in json format to your ajax then check the response if no error then execute the above code i your ajax, .sucess(data){}, .error(data){}. you can add your ajax code here so we can check how it works